# double click on any cell will be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add this function inside the nested loop inside the function
function :

```
$("td").dblclick(function(){
             $(this).html(text(" "));
         });
```

loop :

```
for(var i = 0; i <nr ;i++)
   {
       table_body += '<tr>';
        for(var j = 0; j < nc; j++)
        {
                table_body += '<td class = "cell" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">';
                table_body += '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
                table_body += '</td>';
        }
        table_body += '</tr>';
   }
```

the reason : when i double click on any cell in the table the content will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Attach the listener to the table so it can capture events as they "bubble" up the DOM from the cells.

```js
$('table').on('dblclick', 'td', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  $(this).text('');
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #565656; }
td { border: 1px solid #ababab; padding: 0.2em; }
td:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #ffff00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Bob from accounting</td><td>45</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Stacey</td><td>92</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Steve</td><td>19</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```